# how to check/validate the tar.gz files before un-tar

Tags: files, tar, gzip

when we uncompressed tar.gz file with tar xfz

```
tar xfz redhatPkgInstallation.tar.gz
```

we get the following errors

```
gzip: stdin: decompression OK, trailing garbage ignored
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
failed while , error 2
```

is it possible to check **tar.gz** files propriety before we untar the file?

goal - check/validate the tar.gz file before un-tar ,

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001709/how-to-check-if-a-unix-tar-gz-file-is-a-valid-file-without-uncompressing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Importing from [stackoverflow user John Boker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001709/how-to-check-if-a-unix-tar-gz-file-is-a-valid-file-without-uncompressing), one can do it in several ways:

1. To test the gzip file is not corrupt:

   ```
   gunzip -t file.tar.gz
   ```
2. To test the tar file inside is not corrupt:

   ```
   gunzip -c file.tar.gz | tar t > /dev/null
   ```

Comment: `bunzip2 -t  file.tar.gz` if you used bzip2